# How can I change the object on which a report is based?

Tags: custom-report-type

I created a report and chose Account for the Report Type.  How can I change that to Contacts & Accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report Type is not changable from the UI. Sadly, a solution is to create a new report.